# navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition not working

Tags: javascript, react-native, geolocation

I can't seem to get `navigator.geolocation` to work. It goes into the error function with error code 3, and error message "Location request timed out" What is my code below doing wrong?

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native'
import { App } from './src'

var options = {
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    timeout: 5000,
    maximumAge: 0
  };

  function success(pos) {
    var crd = pos.coords;

    console.log('Your current position is:');
    console.log(`Latitude : ${crd.latitude}`);
    console.log(`Longitude: ${crd.longitude}`);
    console.log(`More or less ${crd.accuracy} meters.`);
  }

  function error(err) {
    console.warn(`ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}`);
  }

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);

GLOBAL.XMLHttpRequest = GLOBAL.originalXMLHttpRequest || GLOBAL.XMLHttpRequest
console.error = (error) => error.apply
AppRegistry.registerComponent('vepo', () => App)
```

Comment: Try removing `maximumAge: 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known location bug in react native and specially Android. Do not send the third parameter (the options one) and see if that works.

If has to do with the highAccuracy and maximumAge

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be to use the HTML and JS code provided by Mozilla:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition#Specifications
Worked the first time I tried it ... the call is in HTML, and the code is in JS.

Here's the HTML code:

```
      <p><button onclick="geoFindMe()">Show my location</button></p>
<div id="out"></div>
```

Here's the JS code:

```
    function geoFindMe() {
                 var output = document.getElementById("out");

             if (!navigator.geolocation){
               output.innerHTML = "<p>Geolocation is not supported by your browser</p>";
               return;
             }

             function success(position) {
               var latitude  = position.coords.latitude;
               var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

               output.innerHTML = '<p>Latitude is ' + latitude + '° <br>Longitude is ' + longitude + '°</p>';

               var img = new Image();
               img.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&zoom=13&size=300x300&sensor=false";

               output.appendChild(img);
             }

             function error() {
               output.innerHTML = "Unable to retrieve your location";
             }

             output.innerHTML = "<p>Locating…</p>";

                 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
     }
```

Note: this code is straight out of Mozilla (link below - see "Geolocation Live Example":

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API

Answer (score 0):

You should request the `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` inside `componentDidMount` or in a function call:

```
componentDidMount() {
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
componentDidMount(){
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                    (position) => {
                               console.log(position)
                                  })
}
```

this work for me, remember add the permission in Android

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It would be better if you checkout [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you